# How to pull checkbox information from the form in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, laravel-5.4

I am working on website in Laravel 5.4 in which I am not sure how to pull checkbox information from the form.

The HTML code copied from the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yn02581o/10/) from where I am using checkbox information is:

```
<div class ="form_check_attachments mt-4 ml-2">
   <div class="form-group  disney_posting_formchecks">
      <div class="form-check mb-3">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
         im interested in setting up a <span style="color:rgb(67, 67, 67);font-weight:bold;">pro</span>Store
         </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check mb-3">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
         <label class="form-check-label">
         I just want to post a thing or two on disney
         </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check mb-3">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
         <label class="form-check-label">
         I wanted to be notified when the app is live
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The controller code which I am using is:

```
   public function store(Request $request)
   {

/*
    dd($request->all());

  */   
      $this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required|email',
      'number' => 'required',
      'city' => 'required',
      'post' => 'required'
      ]);

      Mail::send('emails.posting-message', [
        'msg'=> "Name\t" . $request->name . "\r\n"
        . "Email\t" . $request->email . "\r\n"
        . "Number\t" . $request->number . "\r\n"
        . "City\t" . $request->city . "\r\n"
        . "Message\t" . $request->post . "\r\n"


       ], function($mail) use($request) {

          $mail->from($request->email, $request->name);

           $mail->to('jamalferhan@gmail.com')->subject('Contact Message');
       });

       return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message', 'thank you, your posting info has been sent to our team. we will reach out as soon as we can to provide next steps!');

   }
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the controller so that I am able to pull all the checkbox information. At this moment, it is pulling  the values from the input fields only.

Answer (score 2):

From what I'm seeing in your code, you just need to add the **name attribute** to the input type="checkbox"(checkboxes) so you can see them passed in the request.

Comment: Yes, add the name attribute to each of the checkboxes then update your controller to pull each one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hello" value="hello">Hello
</label>
```

In controller

```
$getcheckboxdata = $request->hello;
```